# How to make keys call methods within C# program

Tags: c#, input, key, keydown

I'm new here, and I may be blasted for not seeing the old posts about Keys, but I assure you I have read many of them and cannot find the answer I am looking for.

I have a C# program, a calculator, that correctly calculates equations, but I want to be able to call methods by both clicking and keyboard input. Like so if user types in <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> the textbox will show 4. The only way the program does that at the moment is if the user actually clicks those buttons. Researching how Keys work in C# I found a lot of information about KeyCode and Keys, but very little information about how to actually implement them within the program. One thing that I came across concerning implementing the code was this:

```
private void Calculator_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Up button was pressed");
        }
    }
```

The name of the form is Calculator. I can compile this code without a problem, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I can place the entire program for you guys if you want, but it is several pages long and has a lot of comments and other stuff. I just don't understand why I can't make my program read a key. I also tried KeyPress instead of KeyDown, still nothing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: 
Marcel N. gave a good answer and I was able to get it to work after enabling the KeyPreview and using the code:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)           
                cmd1.PerformClick();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2)
                cmd2.PerformClick();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3)
                cmd3.PerformClick();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D4)
                cmd4.PerformClick();
             ......................
        }
```

I am very happy that all the numbers work, but am still having issues getting Enter, Divide, Multiply, and the arrow keys to work. Thanks for the speedy help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the form to true.

This will cause all key events to be passed to the form first, before they are delegated to the focused control. Then, you can use your current `KeyDown` handler to call your methods/handlers.

Finally, if you don't want the key events to reach the focused control at all then make sure to set the [`KeyPressEventArgs.Handled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true when you receive the event at the form level.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm. I am still having problems getting Enter to work and the arrow keys.